# Better ways to convert tuple list to string

Tags: c#, string

I have a List in below structure:

```
Tuple<string, string>
```

like this:

[image]

And I would like to join the list to form a string like below:

```
['A', '1'],['B', '2'], ['C', '3']...
```

And I am now using below code to do:

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
      result += "[ '" + list[i].Item1 + "', '" + list[i].Item2 + "'],";
}
```

The code works OK, but would like to ask if there're any better ways to do that?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "better".  Certainly nothing that performs significantly better, unless you have millions of rows and decide to change to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Oh, I mean easier to read.. or this is already the simplest way to write..?

Comment: You could use `string.Format` and/or Linq, but neither of those are _huge_ improvements in my opinion.

Comment: "Easier to read" is completely opinion based... Mine would be to use `String.Join(list, x=> String.Format("['{0}','{1}']", x.Item1, x.Item2)` to represent your exact code. But since I'm known string *escape* master :) I'd just use JSON serializer to avoid all "what if there is quote in one of the elements" issues.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I also want to use JSON serializer if possible... but unfortunately it isn't a json string

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make it more compact by using Linq, `string.Join` and `string.Format`:

```
result = string.Join(",", list.Select(t => string.Format("[ '{0}', '{1}']", t.Item1, t.Item2)));
```

Comment: Mine is better because 'x' > 't' :)

Comment: `t` as in `tuple` :)

Comment: Isn't there a typo inside the string.Format, currently the first parameter is t and it doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes this is not correct. The is no string.Format(Tuple,string,int,int) method available..

Comment: @FranckMesirard Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using `linq` and [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) like this:

```
string.Join(", ", list.Select(t => $"['{t.Item1}', '{t.Item2}']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507290/net-how-to-compare-a-stringbuilder-to-a-string) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133185/stringbuilder-versus-string-concat) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191079/does-stringbuilder-use-more-memory-than-string-concatenation) [benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612797/string-concatenation-vs-string-builder-performance) (note: each word contains one link, but one of the best reference I think is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-effecient-way-to-concatenate-strings).) on how to join the `string`.

Quote from the reference:

> [Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/), the .NET Performance guru, had [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/15/43628.aspx) on this very
>   subject. It's *not as simple as one might suspect*.

You could take a look on `string.Concat` and `string.Builder` in particular, they are usually faster than `+` operator.

Here I use `string.Concat`:

```
string str = string.Concat(new string[] { "[ '", list[i].Item1, "', '", list[i].Item2, "']," });
```

Answer (score 2):

This might also do the trick for you

```
var input = new List<Tuple<string, string>> 
                { 
                    Tuple.Create("A", "1"), 
                    Tuple.Create("B", "2"), 
                    Tuple.Create("C", "3") 
                };
string tpljoined = string.Join(", ", 
                        input.Select(x => "['" + x.Item1 + "','" + x.Item2 + "']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ:

```
var input = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { Tuple.Create("A", "1"), Tuple.Create("B", "2") };
var result = String.Join(",", input.Select(elem => "[ '" + elem.Item1 + "', '" + elem.Item2 + "']"));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```